# Суммировать данные всех массивов

Tags: php

Есть массивы заказов:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [p] => 1200
            [t] => Партер
            [i] => 2:23
            [r] => 2
            [n] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [p] => 1000
            [t] => Партер
            [i] => 10:21
            [r] => 10
            [n] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [p] => 800
            [t] => Партер
            [i] => 18:20
            [r] => 17
            [n] => 1
        )

)
Общая сумма: 3000
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [p] => 1000
            [t] => Партер
            [i] => 10:7
            [r] => 10
            [n] => 15
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [p] => 1000
            [t] => Партер
            [i] => 10:6
            [r] => 10
            [n] => 16
        )

)
Общая сумма: 2000
```

Код выполнения:

```
    foreach ($stats_order as $line) {
        $order_places = unserialize($line->event_places);
        echo '<pre>', print_r( $order_places ), '</pre>';
        $result = array_sum(array_column($order_places, 'p'));
        echo 'Общая сумма: ' . $result;
    }
```

Но как мне сделать, сумму не одного заказа, а сумму всех заказов, если их будет большое множество.

Comment: Не понятно о чём вы.. Приведите пример. Или вы об этом: перед циклом вынесите переменную `$result = 0;` а внутри прибавляйте - не `$result = ...` а `$result += ...`?

Comment: Ну например, вот с этих двух заказов будет общая сумма 5000. Как мне это сделать в коде?

Comment: Написал выше.. Вынесите переменную вне цикла а в цикле прибавляйте к ней

Comment: Можно ещё так (много способов есть) `$sum = array_reduce($array, function($sum, $item){ return $sum += array_sum(array_column($item, 'p')); });`

Comment: Сделал как Вы посоветовали в первом варианте. Общую сумму всех заказов получилось сделать, только почему то, в сумму последнего заказа пишет общую сумму всех заказов.

Comment: Потому что сумма общего заказа это $result (вы её и выводите, но в ней теперь не сумма одного заказа а всех на конкретной итерации), а сумма каждого заказа - то что вы прибавляете к $result, т.е. `array_sum(array_column($order_places, 'p'))` - сумма "текущего" заказа

Comment: Да, дошло как только отправил. Спасибо большое. Буду разбираться, как теперь сумму текущего сделать.

Comment: С чем там разбираться) вынесите в переменную array_sum, а потом прибавляйте эту переменную к $result и выводите её где угодно

Comment: Да, я уже добавил в ответах ))) Спасибо, спасли и объяснили всё.

Answer (score 2):

```
    foreach ($stats_order as $order_event) {
    $order_places = unserialize($order_event->event_places);
    $order_sum = array_sum(array_column($order_places, 'p'));
    $orders_sum += $order_sum;
    echo 'Общая сумма: ' . $order_sum;
}

echo 'Общая сумма заказов: ' . $orders_sum;
```